# Simulating dice rolls and storing the number of runs, R

Tags: r

I have to write a loop that simulates 10^5 sets of 51 tosses of a dice, and stores + sums the number of runs of each length (1,2,3,4).

This is the code that I am using

```
    i <- 0
    sum <- c(0,0,0,0)

    for (i in 1:100000) {
        a <- sample(1:6, 51, replace = TRUE)
        a <- table(rle(a)$lengths)
        a <- as.data.frame(a)
        b <- a[, 2]

        sum <- c(b, rep(0, length(sum) - length(b))) + sum
        i <- i + 1
    }

    print(sum)

}
```

Everything is working except this part (I think this is what is messing it up?):

```
sum <- c(b, rep(0, length(sum) - length(b))) + sum
```

It is giving me this error:
Error in rep(0, length(sum) - length(b)) : invalid 'times' argument

I used this code in another exercise and it was fine but now it doesn't seem to work for certain vectors, can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Here's a hint: when `i` is `1`, what is `length(sum)`? What is `length(b)`? So what is `length(sum) - length(b)`, which is the number you are giving to the `times` argument.?

Comment: Also, when you do `for (i in 1:10000)`, R will automatically start `i` at`1`, then make it `2`, then `3`, etc. You don't need to put `i <- 0` before the loop or `i <- i + 1` inside the loop. (You would need to do that if you were using a `while()` loop instead of a `for()` loop, or if you where keeping track of a *different* counter alongside your loop counter.)

Comment: Oh so to run 100000 loops would I have to do something like `for (i in 1:99999)' instead?

I also found the error, and it was that there would sometimes be runs of 5 which generated another row in the data frame, not really sure how to fix that, do you have any hints?

Sorry I am really new to R, thanks @Gregor!

Comment: No, `1:10000` is fine. There are three numbers in 1, 2, 3. There are 4 in 0, 1, 2, 3. There are 10,000 numbers in 1:10000.

Comment: As for "how to fix it", well, that depends. What do you want to do with runs of 5? (Or 6, or 7, etc., that you may also see with 10k simulations). Ignore them? Count them as 4? Keep track of them individually?

Comment: I'd just like to ignore or remove them, I tried just removing rows that exceed 5 but it doesn't seem to be working, though I'm probably just doing it incorrectly. a <- as.data.frame(a) and then a <- a[-c(5:??)] to remove them

Comment: Though it would be incredibly unlikely to have no runs of length 1, 2, 3, or 4, it would be safer to actually use the value, not the row number: `a <- a[a$Var1 <= 4, ]`

Comment: I tried both of these and they both worked, I decided to just go with @IceCreamToucan's suggestion though. Thanks guys !!